# Picking Unique Combination of records between columns

Tags: sql, oracle, unique

[SOURCE_DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csSEN.png)

Hi,

I am getting source data like above. Basically the 2 tables are describing relationships(actual) between two individuals.

TABLE_1 lists all INDV on application.
TABLE_2 has record for each indv and relation with each member on application.

I need to find unique combination between ID and ID2 fields starting with SEQ_NBR at top. Eldest to youngest.

The data is just for one record. SEQ_NBR 999 can have father there as well and aunt, grandma, etc...

Comment: And what would the results be?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated the question with source data.

Answer (score 0):

> I just need unique combination of all vlaues for 1st and 2nd column.

If you want all combination of the values in the two columns, then use `cross join`:

```
select *
from (select distinct RCPT_NBR from t) x1 cross join
     (select distinct REL_RCPT_NBR from t) x2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data are highly *denormalized*.

Simple decide which relationship you will use and ignore the other.

Example - limiting only to *mother* relationship shows all three persons involved (`ID`s are simplified)

```
select * from tab
where relationship = 'MOTHR';

  PERSON_1   PERSON_2 RELAT
---------- ---------- -----
       224        218 MOTHR
       224        217 MOTHR
```

If you want to order the output *from eldest to youngest* usi a hierarchical query (I added two new persons to the data)

```
WITH t1(person_1, person_2, lvl) AS (
  SELECT person_1,
         person_2,
         1 lvl
  FROM   tab 
  WHERE  person_1 In (select person_1 from tab where relationship = 'MOTHR'
                      minus 
                      select person_2 from tab where relationship = 'MOTHR')
         and relationship = 'MOTHR'             
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t2.person_1,
         t2.person_2,
         t1.lvl + 1 lvl
  FROM   tab t2, t1
  WHERE  t2.person_1 = t1.person_2 and relationship = 'MOTHR'
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY person_1 SET order1
SELECT person_1,
       person_2,
       lvl
FROM   t1
order by order1;

  PERSON_1   PERSON_2        LVL
---------- ---------- ----------
       224        217          1
       224        218          1
       218        222          2
       222        223          3
```

The column `LVL` shows the *generation* i.e. grandmother (1), mother(2) and daugther (3).

To get the *mother* on a highest level you use the `MINUS` query in the anchor part:

```
(select person_1 from tab where relationship = 'MOTHR'
 minus 
select person_2 from tab where relationship = 'MOTHR')
```

This selects all *mother*s that are not *daughter*s, which is what you need.

Comment: the problem is, relatioship can we mother or father at highest level.

Comment: @user3456025 added explanation

Comment: thank you. I have re-stated my question. Can you please review again?